# Pairing a multidimensional array on a while loop

Tags: php, match

How can I pair on a while loop in a given condition if it has found a closest nearest number?

Here is my code variable `$pair`:

```
Array(
      [0]  => Array(
                    ['number']   =>  1800
                    )   
      [1]  => Array(
                    ['number']   =>  1900
                    )
      [2]  => Array(
                    ['number']   =>  2000
                    )  
      [3]  => Array(
                    ['number']   =>  1800
                    )                         
      )
while(sizeof($pair) >= 2) {
 $i = 1;
     $pair_A  =  $pair[0];
     while($i < sizeof($pair)) {
         $pair_B  =  $pair[$i];
         if($pair_A['number'] == $pair_B['number']) {
              //Save to database must pair 1800 of index 0 and 1800 of index 3
         }
         $i++;      
         unset($pair_A);
         unset($pair_B);
     } 

}
```

The issue is I cannot pair both numbers that are equal and satisfies the if condition.

The target is to find in a loop the closest number like a search function without involving any database.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use unset for each loop correctly

```
$j=1
while($j <= sizeof($pair)) {
 $i = 1;
     $pair_A  =  $pair[0];
     while($i <= sizeof($pair)) {
         $pair_B  =  $pair[$i];
         if($pair_A['number'] == $pair_B['number']) {
              //Save to database must pair 1800 of index 0 and 1800 of index 3

         }   
         $i++;  

         unset($pair_B);
     } 
     unset($pair_A);
}
```

Comment: hi @Anto Vinish, the code given gets the matches but it also results to infinite loop.

Comment: why you have used while(sizeof($pair) >= 2) { in the first while that was always true